# More efficient way to parse a matrix in python?

Tags: parsing, matrix, python-2.7, text-files

I have some data in a text file that looks like this:

```
1895723957
8599325893
5723857831
5025852920
```

and I'd like to parse it into a list of lists in Python, so the output is

```
[[1, 8, 9, 5, 7, 2, 3, 9, 5, 7], [8, 5, ...
```

Right now, I have

```
data =  open('file.txt')
rows = [str(line).strip() for line in data]
matrix=[]
for r in rows:
    matrix.append(list(r))
```

but are there different ways to do this, such as using less lines of code or exploiting comprehensions?

I've tried looking around, but I'm not exactly sure what keywords to use here...

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
    matrix = [map(int, line.strip()) for line in handle]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That worked, but I had to use map(int, line.strip()) instead.  I'll look into how map() works.

Comment: You might be able to shave off a second or so if you use `rstrip` instead of `strip`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following way after playing around with comprehensions:

```
data =  open('file.txt')
matrix = [[int(c) for c in row.rstrip()] for row in data]
```

`rstrip` is thanks to Blender above.